# Вернуть данные RxJava

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rxjava, rxandroid

Создал метод `generatePlayer(String, String, ApiService)` в нем использую запросы, а так же  метод `Clan_DannieRx(player.getPersonaly_dannie().getClan_id(), application_id, api);` вызывает еще несколько асинхронных запросов, если условие истинно.
Тут всё работает, все запросы работают правильно. Возник вопрос, после того как все выполнилось, вернуть мне данные назад. `generatePlayer(String, String, ApiService)`стоит пока с типом возврата`void`, но хочу сделать чтоб пользовательский тип данных возвращал.

То есть в другом месте я мог сделать вот так `Person = generatePlayer("name", "2323", api);`

Вот что у меня есть.

```
 public void generatePlayer(final String account_id, final String application_id, final ApiService api)
    {
        final GenerateDannie generateDannie = new GenerateDannie();
        final String[] response = new String[1];
        clan_dannie = new Clan_Dannie();

        ApiService apiMod = RetroClient.getApiServiceMod();
        final HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

        //Генерирует персональные данные
        Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>> FlowablePersonallyDanie = api.getPersonallyDannie(account_id, application_id)
                .mergeWith(api.getInfoTexnika(application_id))  
                .mergeWith(api.getTexnikaPlayer(account_id, application_id))
                .mergeWith(api.getStatistikaTexnika(account_id, application_id))    
                .mergeWith(api.getDostizenie(application_id))   //Достижения
                .mergeWith(api.getDostizeniePlayer(account_id, application_id))  
                .mergeWith(api.getDostizenieTexnika(account_id, application_id)) 
                .mergeWith(apiMod.getModWin8()); 

        FlowablePersonallyDanie
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new FlowableSubscriber<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
                        s.request(Long.MAX_VALUE);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                        //Прилетел ответ
                        try {
                            String url =String.valueOf(responseBodyResponse.raw().request().url());
                            String response = responseBodyResponse.body().string();
                            Log.e("URL", url);
                            Log.e("TAG", response);
                            hashMap.put(url, response);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable t) {
                        //Ошибка
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {
                        //В случае выполнения
                        generatePlayerDannie(hashMap, account_id);
                       if(!player.getPersonaly_dannie().getClan_id().isEmpty())
                           Clan_DannieRx(player.getPersonaly_dannie().getClan_id(), application_id, api);
                       // player.setClan_dannie(clan_dannie);
                    }
                });

    }
```

И метод который обрабатывает результаты

```
    //Генерирует класс из полученных результатов данных игрока
private void generatePlayerDannie(HashMap<String, String> hashMap, String account_id)
{
    Personaly_dannie personaly_dannie = null;
    DostizeniePlayer dostizeniePlayer = null;
    Dostizenie dostizenie = null;
    ArrayList<Dostizenie_Texnika> dostizenie_texnikaArrayList = null;
    Statistika_Texnika statistika_texnika = null;
    ArrayList<Texnika> texnikaArrayList = null;
    Modxvm modxvm = null;


    final GenerateDannie generateDannie = new GenerateDannie();

    for (String key : hashMap.keySet()) {
        if (key.contains(dannie[0])) {
            Log.e("getPersonallyDannie", hashMap.get(key));
           personaly_dannie = generateDannie.getPersonallyDannie(hashMap.get(key), account_id);
            player.setPersonaly_dannie(personaly_dannie);
        }
        else if(key.contains(dannie[1]))
        {
            Log.e("getDostizeniePlayer", hashMap.get(key));
            dostizeniePlayer = generateDannie.getDostizeniePlayer(hashMap.get(key), account_id);
        }
        else if(key.contains(dannie[2]))
        {
            Log.e("getDostizenie", hashMap.get(key));
            dostizenie = generateDannie.getDostizenie(hashMap.get(key));

        }
        else if(key.contains(dannie[3]))
        {
            Log.e("getDostizenieTexnika", hashMap.get(key));
            dostizenie_texnikaArrayList = generateDannie.getDostizenieTexnika(hashMap.get(key), account_id);

        }
        else if(key.contains(dannie[4]))
        {
            Log.e("getStatistika_Texnika", hashMap.get(key));
            statistika_texnika = generateDannie.getStatistika_Texnika(hashMap.get(key), account_id);

        }
        else if(key.contains(dannie[5]))
        {
            Log.e("getRatingClan", hashMap.get(key));
            //clan_dannie.setRating_clan(generateDannieClan.getRatingClan(hashMap.get(key), clan_id));
        }
        else if(key.contains(dannie[6]))
        {
            Log.e("getTexnikaArrayList", hashMap.get(key));
            texnikaArrayList = generateDannie.getTexnikaArrayList(hashMap.get(key));
        }
        else if(key.contains(dannie[7]))
        {
            Log.e("getModx", hashMap.get(key));
            modxvm = generateDannie.getModxvm(hashMap.get(key));
        }
        else
            Log.e("LOL2", hashMap.get(key));
    }

}
```

Comment: так надо возвращать в таком случае `Flowable<Response<ResponseBody>>` и в месте вызова обрабатывать результат

Comment: @andreich, не совсем понял что нужно делать